# Turn off section called "new" in Google Photos app

Tags: privacy, google-photos

When I want to show pics to people, Google Photos first shows whatever is "*new*", for instance "*Screenshots*" below:

[image]

It is often unflattering.

**Question:** How to remove the "*new*" section?

Bonus for removing the "*Throwback to Thursday*"/"*Monday vibes*"/"*Revisit the moment*"/etc sections too, or even better: on app start always show the "*Camera*" collection directly.

Comment: I'm not sure about the "new" section, but for the top section, it's called "Memories": Photo Settings - Memories - Featured memories - (disable all)

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew, I got rid of the first row now!